# Authorization is failed when connecting from windows server to sftp server to retrieve file

Tags: connection, apache-camel, sftp, jsch, apache-karaf

In camel to retrieve file from sftp server to local, written one xml blueprint.
While executing in karaf server abc-sib-1.4.2-R getting below error.

```
org.apache.camel.camel-ftp - 2.15.1 | JSCH -> Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
org.apache.camel.camel-ftp - 2.15.1 | JSCH -> Next authentication method: publickey
org.apache.camel.camel-ftp - 2.15.1 | JSCH -> Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
org.apache.camel.camel-ftp - 2.15.1 | JSCH -> Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
org.apache.camel.camel-ftp - 2.15.1 | JSCH -> Disconnecting from 10.4.13.26(dummy ip) port 8119
```

Please suggest how to resolve the above issue.